# a group that satisfies that the product of operations becomes zero

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, matrices

is there any group or some numbers of math object, number or matrix that satisfies the following:

whenever $AB=0$ where A and B are math objects, some product of the "group" elements, out of them containing A and B, become zero.

edit: so, $ACDBE$ becomes zero.

nonzero matrices assumed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "some product of the 'group' elements, out of them containing A and B, become zero

Comment: @Jeremy edited.

Comment: Yes. $0 \times 0 = 0$, and $0 \times 0 \times 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be a composite number, say, $n=ab$ with $a\gt1,b\gt1$; then in arithmetic modulo $n$, you have $ab=0$, and any product of elements that include an $a$ and a $b$ will be zero.